# TensorBoard doesn't do anything upon execution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Whenever I execute TensorBoard I just get:

```
Starting TensorBoard 54 at http://localhost:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and then nothing happens. Any advice on how to get the graph to show?

EDIT: Sorry I meant to clarify that I copy and paste "http://localhost:6006" into my browser and "No scalar data was found" appears.

FIXED: I was not typing the correct log directory. For anyone in the future who has this problem, don't be like me and assume that TensorBoard automatically reads through the /tmp directory.

Comment: are you sure that you are pointing at the correct log directory, if yes then make sure you are executing and saving the summary operations correctly

Comment: That was it. I assumed TensorBoard automatically started reading in the /tmp directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason might be not giving the correct log directory, and at other times people often forget to write back summaries.